# Tip Top Landscaping Company-word problems

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, probability-distributions

Max has only 9 months and has to take care of 1/4 of the yard, Alex has work for the company longer and has to  takes care of 1/3 of the yard, Steven has been with the company the longest and must care for the remaining 600 square feet. what is the area of the yard? Ho wlong have Alex and Steven worked for the Landscaping Company

Comment: What does the time they've worked for the company have to do with how much of the yard they take care of?

Comment: @vadim123 Isn't that just deliberate obfuscation?

Comment: @SuzuHirose, the second question is about time worked.

Comment: @vadim123 Sorry I didn't notice that. Anyway that needs some guesswork since it doesn't explicitly say the length of time worked is proportional to the amount of yard they have to do.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
9:A:S=\frac14:&\frac13:\frac5{12}=X:Y:600\\
\\
9:A:S=3:&4:5=X:Y:600\\
\\
9:12:15=3:&4:5=360:480:600\\
\\
A=12, S=15&; X=360, Y=480
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is the fraction Steven looks after, then $1/3+1/4+x = 1$. Now if $A$ is the area then $Ax=600$. Working the fractions gives $x=1-1/3-1/4=12/12-4/12-3/12=5/12$ so $A\times5/12=600$. Now solve for $A$.